# How can I generate an interrupted projection of a world map?

Tags: graphics, geodesy, projection

How can I generate a world map like the one [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/geographic-visualization/make-a-map-that-wraps-a-globe.html), but for an arbitrary hand-drawn map?

For example, starting from scratch, how can I manipulate this world map

[image]

to get something that looks like this?

[image]

**Attempt**: Starting with the world map, I thought to cut the image into vertical strips and somehow contract each rectangular strip at its upper and lower ends while keeping the middle constant to make symmetric [lenses](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lens.html), i.e. the transformation that does this:

[image]

However, I don't how to do this, and I suspect there may be an easier way. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Your first image seems to be cut off (i.e. not a complete equirectangular projection of the world).

Comment: Wolfram Research has posted a page, Make a Map That Wraps a Globe. There you can find Mathematica code that should answer your question; follow [this link](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/geographic-visualization/make-a-map-that-wraps-a-globe.html)

Comment: @m_goldberg I was aware of that page (it was the first link I included in my question). I am asking how to do something similar but with an arbitrary map, say the map of some fictional planet, not one of Earth. I wasn't aware that the code given on that page could be adapted for an imported image as JM's answer demonstrated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm going to take the interpretation that you want to apply the [transverse Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator_projection) to an image you have to produce something like the one in [the Wolfram page](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/geographic-visualization/make-a-map-that-wraps-a-globe.html) you linked to. One only needs to make a few changes to the code in that link. I will be using a different image, since the one in the OP is awkwardly cut off, which will mess with the mapping.

```
With[{Δ = 30},
     earth = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jteWq.jpg"];
     ImageAssemble[MapThread[Rasterize[
          GeoGraphics[GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", #2}], 
                      GeoRange -> {{-90, 90}, #1[[1]]}, 
                      GeoProjection -> {"TransverseMercator", "Centering" -> #1[[2]]},
                      ImageSize -> Large], 
                    ImageSize -> Large] &,
                    {Table[{{λ, λ + Δ}, {0, λ + Δ/2}}, {λ, -180, 180 - Δ, Δ}],
                     First @ ImagePartition[earth, Scaled[{Δ/360, 1}]]}]]]
```

[image: transverse Mercator]

---

Here is a *slower* method that uses `ImageTransformation[]` and formulae 22-23 from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MercatorProjection.html) to directly transform the map (note that I took the liberty to work directly in radians instead of degrees):

```
With[{Δ = π/6},
     earth = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jteWq.jpg"];
     ImageAssemble[Table[ImageTransformation[earth, 
                   Module[{x = #[[1]], y = #[[2]], h = Δ/2, λt},
                          λt = ArcTan[Cos[y], Sinh[x]]; 
                          If[-h <= λt <= h,
                             {λ + h + λt, ArcSin[Sin[y] Sech[x]]},
                             {π, π/2} (* dummy value for off-range pixels *)]] &, 
                   Background -> White, DataRange -> {{-π, π}, {-π/2, π/2}}, 
                   Masking -> All, 
                   PlotRange -> {{-InverseGudermannian[Δ/2], InverseGudermannian[Δ/2]},
                                 {-π/2, π/2}}],
                   {λ, -π, π - Δ, Δ}]]]
```

[image: directly transformed image]

Comment: Bonus image: [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YdN6y.png) is the result of applying the piecewise transverse Mercator projection to the [ETOPO1 global relief](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/).

Comment: This looks quite promising. I'll give it a try when I get to my desktop.

Comment: @J.M. What would be the parametric equation for a single flat gore region?

Comment: @Young, pardon me, but what is a "flat gore region"?

Comment: I'm trying this `img = Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/jteWq.jpg"];
gore = 12;
tex = First@ImagePartition[img, Scaled[{1/gore, 1}]];
Row[Table[
  ParametricPlot[{phi Sin[theta]^2, 
    gore/2 phi Cos[theta]}, {phi, -Pi/gore, Pi/gore}, {theta, -Pi, Pi},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[tex[[i]]], Opacity[1]], 
   TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &),
   Frame -> False, Axes -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   ImageSize -> Medium],
  {i, 1, gore}]]`

Comment: @Young, you might want to look at formulae 19-21 at the MathWorld link I gave: `With[{λ = π/12}, ParametricPlot[{ArcTanh[Cos[ϕ] Sin[λ]], ArcTan[Cos[ϕ] Cos[λ], Sin[ϕ]]}, {ϕ, -π/2, π/2}]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Exactly what I was looking for ... I didn't notice the reference in the post at first. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

J.M.'s answer is the best and he helped me figure out the correct parametric equations from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MercatorProjection.html), but the method I've been working on is very fast (<0.5 sec) and doesn't include any white-space where the slices connect.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jteWq.jpg"];
gore = 12;
tex = First @ ImagePartition[img, Scaled[{1/gore, 1}]];
ImageAssemble[Table[
  ParametricPlot[{ArcTanh[Cos[ϕ] Sin[λ]],  ArcTan[Cos[ϕ] Cos[λ], Sin[ϕ]]},
   {ϕ, -π/2, π/2}, {λ, -π/gore, π/gore},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[tex[[i]]], Opacity[1]], 
   TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), Frame -> False, 
   Axes -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotRangePadding -> 0],
  {i, 1, gore}]]
```

[image: Mercator-projected map]

Comment: Here's an alternative: `Show[Table[ParametricPlot[{2 (i - 1) InverseGudermannian[π/gore] + ArcTanh[Cos[ϕ] Sin[λ]], ArcTan[Cos[ϕ] Cos[λ], Sin[ϕ]]}, {ϕ, -π/2, π/2}, {λ, -π/gore, π/gore}, Axes -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[tex[[i]]], Opacity[1]], TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &)], {i, 1, gore}], PlotRange -> All]`.